# perform nothing when call execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

this is my asynctask class....................

```
public class  UpdatingNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Database_WebService webservice;
    private Context mContext;

    public UpdatingNews(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        webservice = new Database_WebService(mContext);
        webservice.updateallCatNews();
        webservice.UpdateAllNews();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Main_Launcher.this,
                Main_FormNewUser.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

When i call it..................

```
update = new UpdatingNews(this);
    check = webservice.CheckSurveySubmit();
    int secondsDelayed = 3;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (check == 0) {
                update.execute("...");



            }
            if (check == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main_Launcher.this,
                        Main_AllLatestNews.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

It did not perform..............................

```
webservice.updateallCatNews();
        webservice.UpdateAllNews();
```

What is the problem there????????????????????????????

Comment: What is `Database_WebService` ?

Comment: Database_WebService contain those functions are dealing with sqlite database

Comment: Unless you post all source cdoes here (including webservice, activity etc), it's not possible to know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UpdatingNews` is an AsyncTask. In your run(), you started the task, but then immediately start another activity, without finishing the task. Most probably, android move to `Main_FormNewUser` Activity, but the task is still running in the background. 
So, very likely that your second run is actually having the results from the first run.

If you need the next activity appears *After* you grab the News, you should move your `startActivity` statement to `onPostExecute()` in the asynctask.

Comment: I mean first run (alt + f11), no perform anything, then quit and run
second run (alt + f12), do perform.

i tried before, start activity in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: By what you posted here, it is hard to further determine why it is not working. No idea how you perform the update and how you evaluate it is not performing. Did the UpdatingNews really gets called?

Answer (score 0):

After looking your code, I think xandy is correct. Main_FormNewUser Activity is executing  in parallel with Async task.

Comment: i had updated the post, please have a look again @Aniket Rane